# Push _back for your own STL container C++

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to write a class template that is used to contain sequences of elements. I am working on a method that will behave like push_back() in vector. This is what i have done so far:

```
template <class T, int N>
class mysequence{
    T memblock[N];
public:
    void setmember(T value);
    T getmember(int x);
};

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::setmember(T value) {
    if (sizeof(memblock) == 1) memblock[0] = value;
    else {
        int y = sizeof(memblock) / sizeof(memblock[0]);
        memblock[y] = value;
    }
}

template <class T, int N>
T mysequence<T, N>::getmember(int x) {
    return memblock[x];
}



    int main()
    {

        mysequence < int, 14 > myints;
        myints.setmember(9);
        cout << myints.getmember(0);

    }
```

And it returns:

```
-858993460
```

with error message. As far as i know the sizeof an empty class or structure is 1. But i also tried:

```
if (sizeof(memblock) == NULL) memblock[0] = value;
```

But all the same. I can not figure out what`s wrong with my code. If anyone has any ideas, i will apressiate it.

Comment: So to clarify if you have a sequence of calls to `setmember` such as 1,5,8 then you would expect to see `getmember(0)` be `1`,  `getmember(1)` be `5` and `getmember(2)` be `8`?

Comment: `if (sizeof(memblock) == NULL)`.. really? First of all, `sizeof` isn't a function, secondly, comparing the result of this operator to `NULL` is nonsense, because it's not a pointer, and last but not least, it cannot ever be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking `getmember()` to return the first element of the array, but `setmember()` never fills in that element **unless** `T` is `char`, `unsigned char`, or `bool`, and `N` is 1.  In any other combination, `setmember()` is storing the value **past the end of the array**.  If you want to store a value in the last element, use N-1 instead (no need to calculate `y` as it will match `N`):

```
template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::setmember(T value) {
    memblock[N-1] = value;
}
```

But, that is no use in a multi-element array.  Since you want to mimic `push_back()`, you need to have `setmember()` store the value in the **last available element** instead:

```
template <class T, int N>
class mysequence{
    T memblock[N];
    int count;
public:
   mysequence() : count(0) {}
    void setmember(T value);
    T getmember(int x);
};

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::setmember(T value) {
    if (count < N) {
        memblock[count-1] = value;
        ++count;
    }
    else
        throw length_error("sequence is full");
}

template <class T, int N>
T mysequence<T, N>::getmember(int x) {
    if ((x < 0) || (x >= count))
        throw out_of_range("x is out of range");
    return memblock[x];
}
```

```
int main()
{
    mysequence < int, 14 > myints;
    myints.setmember(9);
    cout << myints.getmember(0);    
}
```

Or, you could simply get rid of your array and use a real vector instead:

```
template <class T>
class mysequence{
    vector<T> memblock;
public:
    void setmember(T value);
    T getmember(int x);
};

template <class T>
void mysequence<T>::setmember(T value) {
    memblock.push_back(value);
}

template <class T>
T mysequence<T>::getmember(int x) {
    return memblock[x];
}
```

```
int main()
{
    mysequence < int > myints;
    myints.setmember(9);
    cout << myints.getmember(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is your use of sizeof. It does not tell you how many elements do you have, but just the memory used (N * sizeof(T)). To keep track of elements contained you seed a separate counter.

Answer (score 0):

This should indicate the problem:

```
template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::setmember(T value) {
    if (sizeof(memblock) == 1) memblock[0] = value;
    else {
        int y = sizeof(memblock) / sizeof(memblock[0]);
        cout << "y: " << y << endl;
        memblock[y] = value;
    }
}
```

When called with:

```
myints.setmember(1);
myints.setmember(5);
myints.setmember(8);
```

I get the output:

```
y: 14
y: 14
y: 14
```

`y` is always the same because it's calculated by finding the length of the underlying storage array, not the number of elements actually stored in that array.

Given that we aren't filling in the elements of the array correctly the values we get when we call `getmember` will be pulling out uninitialized elements of the array. This is where you get the garbage values such as `-858993460` from (note that on my machine I got a different value here which is in line with the UB we have here).

If you want to support a `push_back` type of method that doesn't require an index to be passed in with the value then you need to change your design to have a field that keeps track of how many elements you have inserted into the array so far.

Additionally I'd make some checks to see if there is enough space to actually put the newest element into the back of the array before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the functionality of push_back. What push_back does is that it adds elements to the end of an array, even an empty array. So I have modified some functionality of your functions and indicated them in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
class mysequence{
    T *memblock;//You will need a pointer for enabling the resizing of the array
    int size;//This is used to keep track of the size of the array
public:
    mysequence();
    mysequence(const mysequence &src);
    ~mysequence();
    void setmember(T value);
    T getmember(int x);
    void push_back(T value);
    mysequence& operator=(const mysequence &src);
};

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::mysequence(){
    size = N;
    memblock = new T[N];
}

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::mysequence(const mysequence<T,N> &src){
    size = src.size
    memblock = new T[size];
    copy(src.memblock, src.memblock+size, memblock);
}

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::~mysequence(){
    delete[] memblock;
}

template <class T, int N>
void mysequence<T, N>::setmember(T value) {//this setmember function just sets the last element of the array to the value specified
    if( size > 0 ){
        memblock[size-1] = value;
    }
}

template<class T, int N>
void mysequence<T,N>::push_back(T value){
    T *pointer = new T[size+1];
    copy(memblock, memblock+size, pointer);
    pointer[size] = value;
    delete[] arr;
    arr = pointer;
    size++;
}

template <class T, int N>
T mysequence<T, N>::getmember(int x) {
    return memblock[x];
}

template<class T, int N>
mysequence<T,N>& mysequence<T,N>::operator=(const mysequence<T,N> &src){
    T *pointer = new T[src.size];
    copy(src.memblock, src.memblock+src.size, pointer);
    delete[] arr;
    arr = pointer;
    size = src.size;
}

    int main()
    {

        mysequence < int, 14 > myints;
        myints.setmember(9);
        cout << myints.getmember(13)<<endl;//the indexing is one less. so to access the last element, you need to specify 13. As other values are not initialized, they will have garbage value in them
        myints.push_back(1);
        cout<<myints.getmember(14)<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is C++, not C.  Use `new[]` instead of `malloc()`, which is especially important if `T` is not a primitive type, and consider expanding `memblock` in chunks so you do not have to reallocate memory on every `push_back()` call. Also, you need a copy constructor and assignment operator to make copies of `memblock` correctly, and a destructor to free `memblock`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the correction. I have made the necessary changes. However, I have assumed T to be inbuilt and thus haven't shown the copy constructor and the destructor part

Comment: even if `T` is a built-in type, you still need a destructor to free the array, and a copy constructor and assignment operator to copy the array correctly from one `mysequence` object to another, otherwise they end pointing at the same array and you leak an array. See [rule of thread/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have modified and indicated the copy part in the comment